# convert xs:boolean value to Java Boolean

Tags: java, xml

Given the `xs:boolean` lexical scope in XSD (true, 1, false, 0), is there an Apache commons / Guava or other widely used 3rd party-library that converts from a String value of that type to a Java `Boolean` type?

I guess I can implement my own as below but for something that's presumably so widely needed and used I would prefer to use a standard library.

```
public static Boolean fromXSDBoolean(String _xsdBoolean) {
    /* XSD specification:
       Lexical representation
       An instance of a datatype that is defined as boolean can have the 
       following legal literals {true, false, 1, 0}. 
    */
    if (_xsdBoolean==null)
        return null;
    String xsdBoolean = _xsdBoolean.trim();
    if ("".equals(xsdBoolean))
        return null;
    switch (xsdBoolean) {
    case "true":
    case "1":
        return true;
    case "false":
    case "0":
        return false;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(_xsdBoolean);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the JAXB `DatatypeConverter` class that is in the JDK/JRE as part of Java SE 6:

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean("0")     // false
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean("  0  ") // false      
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean("1")     // true
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean("  1  ") // true
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean("false") // false
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean("true")  // true
```

**Note:**  An input of empty `String` or `null` will result in a `NullPointerException` so you will need to check these inputs before calling `parseBoolean`.

Comment: This is good but sadly we also have
`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBoolean("not a boolean") // false but document as throwing IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Also note, that values like `"truo"` and `"truoo"` are also converted to `true`.